# How do I get a pyTelegramBotAPI container service running on Google Cloud Run (GCP)?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, port, py-telegram-bot-api

I can't get pyTelegramBotAPI working on Google Cloud Run. I keep getting a port related error.

**Disclaimers:**

- I'm a noob. I'm relatively new to GCP, containers, and Python.
- logical-bank-359221 is not my real GCP ID, I've intentionally changed it in the logs. Please don't let that throw you off.

So I have a Python bot that I've written but I've simplified it down and its still not working.

**Expected behaviour:**

What I was trying to do was have a Python Telegram bot running constantly on Google Cloud Run and for it always to respond to requests. So that when I send messages to the bot on the Telegram app on my phone, it would always respond accordingly.

**Observed behaviour:**

After loading and running the code in a container ([screenshot of my Cloud Run service setup options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnJIH.png)), it crashes after around a minute. During the time its running, it responds to requests properly and when I type `/hi` to the Telegram bot on my phone, I get a "Hello world" response, I can do this many times but after about 5 minutes ([screenshot of what I see on Cloud Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWJ2O.png)) the container stops on Google Cloud Run with the following error ([screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2NlA.png)):

```
 The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information. Logs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=logical-fort-359211&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/telegram-test-bot/revision_name/telegram-test-bot-00001-jic&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22telegram-test-bot%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22telegram-test-bot-00001-jic%22  For more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start
```

When I build and run the container locally, it works without problem, its stable and responds to all requests without problem.

**What I've tried to do but haven't really gotten anywhere:**

1. I've tried to start the container with different port settings settings: 80, 88, 443, 8080, 8443. No real change in behaviour.
2. I built and ran the container locally on (Docker), got in via CLI, installed netstat and some other tools that I googled to see what specific port it listens on, but I couldn't work it out. Googling pyTelegramBotAPI for default ports also didn't tell me what specific port I needed to open. If any. I'm guessing there must be some specific port that requests are coming in from to the bot but I couldn't find an answer.
3. I tried setting playing with the ```EVN PORT`` setting in the Dockerfile. But it also didn't make much difference. I paired it up with what I had configured the container image through Google Cloud Run but no change in observed behaviour.

**Code and Logs:**

*telegram_test_bot.py:*

```
import telebot

# I've intentionally starred this out
bot = telebot.TeleBot("5508342368:AAGTs5s-xuQBT5kbmhu_*********") 

@bot.message_handler(commands=['hi'])
def handle_command(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Hello world")
    
bot.polling()
```

*Dockerfile:*

```
FROM python:3

ADD telegram_test_bot.py /

RUN pip install pyTelegramBotAPI

CMD [ "python", "./telegram_test_bot.py" ]
```

*Creating the container and having it be stored on Google Container Registry:*

```
xxxxxxx@cloudshell:~/telegram_test_bot (logical-bank-359221)$ gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/logical-bank-359221/test_bot_image .
Creating temporary tarball archive of 2 file(s) totalling 338 bytes before compression.
Uploading tarball of [.] to [gs://logical-bank-359221_cloudbuild/source/1661579400.083045-20d26c4f7c23435d94ddaf6ed9d394ca.tgz]
Created [https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/logical-bank-359221/locations/global/builds/2c92efa5-0669-4c99-a8cc-a7f350c50676].
Logs are available at [ https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/2c92efa5-0669-4c99-a8cc-a7f350c50676?project=518622666562 ].
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- REMOTE BUILD OUTPUT -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
starting build "2c92efa5-0669-4c99-a8cc-a7f350c50676"

FETCHSOURCE
Fetching storage object: gs://logical-bank-359221_cloudbuild/source/1661579400.083045-20d26c4f7c23435d94ddaf6ed9d394ca.tgz#1661579400971313
Copying gs://logical-bank-359221_cloudbuild/source/1661579400.083045-20d26c4f7c23435d94ddaf6ed9d394ca.tgz#1661579400971313...
/ [1 files][  470.0 B/  470.0 B]
Operation completed over 1 objects/470.0 B.
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.072kB
Step 1/4 : FROM python:3
3: Pulling from library/python
1671565cc8df: Pulling fs layer
3e94d13e55e7: Pulling fs layer
fa9c7528c685: Pulling fs layer
53ad072f9cd1: Pulling fs layer
d6b983117533: Pulling fs layer
d8092d56ded5: Pulling fs layer
c71afc637d59: Pulling fs layer
864a10b3c704: Pulling fs layer
4334b2fe8293: Pulling fs layer
d8092d56ded5: Waiting
53ad072f9cd1: Waiting
d6b983117533: Waiting
c71afc637d59: Waiting
4334b2fe8293: Waiting
864a10b3c704: Waiting
3e94d13e55e7: Verifying Checksum
3e94d13e55e7: Download complete
fa9c7528c685: Verifying Checksum
fa9c7528c685: Download complete
1671565cc8df: Verifying Checksum
1671565cc8df: Download complete
53ad072f9cd1: Verifying Checksum
53ad072f9cd1: Download complete
d8092d56ded5: Verifying Checksum
d8092d56ded5: Download complete
864a10b3c704: Download complete
4334b2fe8293: Verifying Checksum
4334b2fe8293: Download complete
c71afc637d59: Verifying Checksum
c71afc637d59: Download complete
d6b983117533: Verifying Checksum
d6b983117533: Download complete
1671565cc8df: Pull complete
3e94d13e55e7: Pull complete
fa9c7528c685: Pull complete
53ad072f9cd1: Pull complete
d6b983117533: Pull complete
d8092d56ded5: Pull complete
c71afc637d59: Pull complete
864a10b3c704: Pull complete
4334b2fe8293: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:745efdfb7e4aac9a8422bd8c62d8bc35a693e8979a240d29677cb03e6aa91052
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3
 d25a66380b10
Step 2/4 : ADD telegram_test_bot.py /
 b609762a1056
Step 3/4 : RUN pip install pyTelegramBotAPI
 Running in 7a3126f23a77
Collecting pyTelegramBotAPI
  Downloading pyTelegramBotAPI-4.7.0.tar.gz (210 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 210.7/210.7 kB 18.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting requests
  Downloading requests-2.28.1-py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 62.8/62.8 kB 10.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Downloading urllib3-1.26.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl (140 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 140.4/140.4 kB 22.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting charset-normalizer<3,>=2
  Downloading charset_normalizer-2.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Downloading certifi-2022.6.15-py3-none-any.whl (160 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 160.2/160.2 kB 24.4 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Collecting idna<4,>=2.5
  Downloading idna-3.3-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 61.2/61.2 kB 10.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Building wheels for collected packages: pyTelegramBotAPI
  Building wheel for pyTelegramBotAPI (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pyTelegramBotAPI (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for pyTelegramBotAPI: filename=pyTelegramBotAPI-4.7.0-py3-none-any.whl size=192810 sha256=68ed7e6a9e295e69d53c1cde07f06da81bcd56fa7e784ce113b61d5ae3052721
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/66/e7/a6/1fd4c399389e73024eae09e705cf0554ab1706465ac0c6e913
Successfully built pyTelegramBotAPI
Installing collected packages: urllib3, idna, charset-normalizer, certifi, requests, pyTelegramBotAPI
Successfully installed certifi-2022.6.15 charset-normalizer-2.1.1 idna-3.3 pyTelegramBotAPI-4.7.0 requests-2.28.1 urllib3-1.26.12
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.2.1 -> 22.2.2
[notice] To update, run: pip install --upgrade pip
Removing intermediate container 7a3126f23a77
 42605d43b39c
Step 4/4 : CMD [ "python", "./telegram_test_bot.py" ]
 Running in d944d85efa80
Removing intermediate container d944d85efa80
 9877e24eadcd
Successfully built 9877e24eadcd
Successfully tagged gcr.io/logical-bank-359221/test_bot_image:latest
PUSH
Pushing gcr.io/logical-bank-359221/test_bot_image
The push refers to repository [gcr.io/logical-bank-359221/test_bot_image]
498a8e9bfed3: Preparing
df7847f5e574: Preparing
bfc1deb8136e: Preparing
1f123186824c: Preparing
3d6eb1152931: Preparing
100796cdf3b1: Preparing
54acb5a6fa0b: Preparing
8d51c618126f: Preparing
9ff6e4d46744: Preparing
a89d1d47b5a1: Preparing
655ed1b7a428: Preparing
100796cdf3b1: Waiting
54acb5a6fa0b: Waiting
8d51c618126f: Waiting
9ff6e4d46744: Waiting
a89d1d47b5a1: Waiting
655ed1b7a428: Waiting
3d6eb1152931: Layer already exists
bfc1deb8136e: Layer already exists
1f123186824c: Layer already exists
8d51c618126f: Layer already exists
54acb5a6fa0b: Layer already exists
100796cdf3b1: Layer already exists
9ff6e4d46744: Layer already exists
a89d1d47b5a1: Layer already exists
655ed1b7a428: Layer already exists
df7847f5e574: Pushed
498a8e9bfed3: Pushed
latest: digest: sha256:3abc7582a687051656e262480bc6fc6db2e9b2cf761e18a84b4d98e6b6801c9f size: 2636
DONE
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ID: 2c92efa5-0669-4c99-a8cc-a7f350c50676
CREATE_TIME: 2022-08-27T05:50:02+00:00
DURATION: 40S
SOURCE: gs://logical-bank-359221_cloudbuild/source/1661579400.083045-20d26c4f7c23435d94ddaf6ed9d394ca.tgz
IMAGES: gcr.io/logical-bank-359221/test_bot_image (+1 more)
STATUS: SUCCESS
xxxxxxx@cloudshell:~/telegram_test_bot (logical-bank-359221)$
```

*Google Cloud run log:*

```
{
  "protoPayload": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 9,
      "message": "Ready condition status changed to False for Revision telegram-test-bot-00001-jic with message: The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.\n\nLogs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=logical-bank-359221&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/telegram-test-bot/revision_name/telegram-test-bot-00001-jic&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22telegram-test-bot%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22telegram-test-bot-00001-jic%22 \nFor more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start"
    },
    "serviceName": "run.googleapis.com",
    "resourceName": "namespaces/logical-bank-359221/revisions/telegram-test-bot-00001-jic",
    "response": {
      "metadata": {
        "name": "telegram-test-bot-00001-jic",
        "namespace": "518622666562",
        "selfLink": "/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/518622666562/revisions/telegram-test-bot-00001-jic",
        "uid": "23f46b3d-ca6e-427e-81bf-946848aa1177",
        "resourceVersion": "AAXnMt74Vh4",
        "generation": 1,
        "creationTimestamp": "2022-08-27T06:05:10.428910Z",
        "labels": {
          "serving.knative.dev/route": "telegram-test-bot",
          "serving.knative.dev/configuration": "telegram-test-bot",
          "serving.knative.dev/configurationGeneration": "1",
          "serving.knative.dev/service": "telegram-test-bot",
          "serving.knative.dev/serviceUid": "9ff9148c-f1e0-428c-967d-8d03ec384ca5",
          "cloud.googleapis.com/location": "us-central1"
        },
        "annotations": {
          "run.googleapis.com/client-name": "cloud-console",
          "serving.knative.dev/creator": "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com",
          "autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale": "100",
          "run.googleapis.com/cpu-throttling": "true"
        },
        "ownerReferences": [
          {
            "kind": "Configuration",
            "name": "telegram-test-bot",
            "uid": "9625ff54-4278-46f4-a425-9b5de34be2f8",
            "apiVersion": "serving.knative.dev/v1",
            "controller": true,
            "blockOwnerDeletion": true
          }
        ]
      },
      "apiVersion": "serving.knative.dev/v1",
      "kind": "Revision",
      "spec": {
        "containerConcurrency": 80,
        "timeoutSeconds": 300,
        "serviceAccountName": "518622666562-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "test_bot_image-1",
            "image": "gcr.io/logical-bank-359221/test_bot_image@sha256:3abc7582a687051656e262480bc6fc6db2e9b2cf761e18a84b4d98e6b6801c9f",
            "ports": [
              {
                "name": "http1",
                "containerPort": 8080
              }
            ],
            "resources": {
              "limits": {
                "cpu": "1000m",
                "memory": "512Mi"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "status": {
        "observedGeneration": 1,
        "conditions": [
          {
            "type": "Ready",
            "status": "False",
            "reason": "HealthCheckContainerError",
            "message": "The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.\n\nLogs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=logical-bank-359221&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/telegram-test-bot/revision_name/telegram-test-bot-00001-jic&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22telegram-test-bot%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22telegram-test-bot-00001-jic%22 \nFor more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start",
            "lastTransitionTime": "2022-08-27T06:09:18.751262Z"
          },
          {
            "type": "Active",
            "status": "True",
            "lastTransitionTime": "2022-08-27T06:05:16.218844Z",
            "severity": "Info"
          },
          {
            "type": "ContainerHealthy",
            "status": "False",
            "reason": "HealthCheckContainerError",
            "message": "The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.\n\nLogs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=logical-bank-359221&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/telegram-test-bot/revision_name/telegram-test-bot-00001-jic&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22telegram-test-bot%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22telegram-test-bot-00001-jic%22 \nFor more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start",
            "lastTransitionTime": "2022-08-27T06:09:18.751262Z"
          },
          {
            "type": "ResourcesAvailable",
            "status": "True",
            "lastTransitionTime": "2022-08-27T06:05:16.024073Z"
          },
          {
            "type": "Retry",
            "status": "True",
            "reason": "ImmediateRetry",
            "message": "System will retry after 0:00:00 from lastTransitionTime for attempt 0.",
            "lastTransitionTime": "2022-08-27T06:09:18.751262Z",
            "severity": "Info"
          }
        ],
        "logUrl": "https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=logical-bank-359221&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/telegram-test-bot/revision_name/telegram-test-bot-00001-jic&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22telegram-test-bot%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22telegram-test-bot-00001-jic%22",
        "imageDigest": "gcr.io/logical-bank-359221/test_bot_image@sha256:3abc7582a687051656e262480bc6fc6db2e9b2cf761e18a84b4d98e6b6801c9f"
      },
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.run.v1.Revision"
    }
  },
  "insertId": "mrnhofc3ce",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_run_revision",
    "labels": {
      "service_name": "telegram-test-bot",
      "project_id": "logical-bank-359221",
      "location": "us-central1",
      "revision_name": "telegram-test-bot-00001-jic",
      "configuration_name": "telegram-test-bot"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2022-08-27T06:05:18.487736Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "logName": "projects/logical-bank-359221/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fsystem_event",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2022-08-27T06:09:19.760286025Z"
}
```

Somebody please help!! This is doing my head in! Let me know if there's something else I can do to diagnose the issue. Remember, I'm a proper noob. Spoonfeed me please :)

Comment: Your problem is this **The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable**. Your container does not start an HTTP server or TCP listener on port 8080. Rewrite your application to listen for and responds to HTTP requests.

Comment: Have you succeded with running telegram-cli at least anywhere? I get `API_64BIT_LOGIN_APP_OUTDATED_254: You are using an outdated app that is no longer supported`